# CSS last A from an UL LI list

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less

I need to select the last element A, from an ul li list
CSS like .items:last-child, get the li, but i need only the A related to LINK 3

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="items"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <li id="items"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <li id="items"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid: a quotation mark is missing after `id="items`; using the same id more than once on the same document is invalid. And those `id`s are actually unneeded.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `> a` a to get immediate child of type `a` directly:

```css
.items:last-child > a {
  /* your css here... */
}
```

by the way, just noticed that you are using `id` attribute for items, in that case you need to switch to:

```css
#items:last-child > a {
  /* your css here... */
}
```